# Constraining image height with bootstrap responsive image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a site using bootstrap, in the portfolio section, the images of projects are responsive with :

```
'class' => 'img-responsive'
```

It works great for landscape images, the portrait images are blown up to fit width wise, but are too tall, is there a way to check for a portrait orientated image and just apply a fixed height of 600px for it?

Answer (score 54):

If the container should have a fixed height, then give it an ID (or a class) and change the .img-responsive restrictions the other way around eg

```
.container {
height: 600px;
}


/*And then change */
  .container .img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}  
/*To */

.container  .img-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Not sure how it will work with a mix of orientations but if they are floated it shouldnt really matter

Comment: This worked for me. I think this should be marked as the answer. Kudos @MrPeeps.

Comment: Great answer, I have to add max-width: 100% in .img-responsive class; to make sure wider images also fit inside the container.