# Bootstrap responsive image fit to parent height, stretching full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive-images

I have a row with a certain height (e.g. 600px) and would like fit an img (size 1920x1080) into this row, stretching responsively 100% to the row width but not exceeding the height.

In other words, only 600px of the height of the image should be shown (the rest can be cut off, hidden, etc.), and it should remain responsive to the row width. To illustrate, only the part within the red borders should show:

[image]

The problem I am having is that "img-fluid" always fits the image to the smaller height of the container, and thus shrinking the width to keep the aspect ratio. Without img-fluid, or adding a fixed height to the image, the aspect ratio gets lost and the image is "squeezed" into the row-container. My code:

```css
.img-400 {
  height: 400px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row img-400">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iG8OSb/dogs.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note I tried this one: [Constraining image height with bootstrap responsive image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708979/constraining-image-height-with-bootstrap-responsive-image) but didn't work, it keeps scaling the img out of the container.

Answer (score 1):

the above solution works if the .img-fluid is not manipulated:

```css
.img-400 {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi try this one,

```
.img-400 img{ width: 100% ; }
```

Hope this helps :)